How to have an xml (which is taken as a string in the UI) and I need to send this XML in the request body to the backend API. I am getting errors
I am sending a requestDTO as follows:
{
  "transportType": 0,
  "registerMode": 4,
  "siteName": "string",
  "destinationAddress": "string",
  "messageContent": "string",
  "timeout": 0
}

The messageContent is a string (which contains XML data like <param>"1233"</param>) provided by the user. I am encountering different errors when sending this request body through an HTTP POST request.
One of the issues is related to the escape sequence for double quotes (""). Additionally, for a specific input like <Parameter Name="BatchId">0xc70fe820ee010080</Parameter>, it throws an error indicating there is an issue in the JSON while parsing 0xc70fe820ee010080.
Where and why is it failing?

for some reason i am unable to paste the xml as the tags are not coming in the input /comment box.

also i am getting this error
the xml exception is '&' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 3, position 17. when trying to parse this value in xml tags 0xc70fe820ee010080

for quotes you need to encode them: "1233". If it is user input you need to parse the string and replace any chars like <,> and "

Thanks Rob , my API needs it in the XML form so , should i convert it back to xml in C# .NET  once I get this json in my backend code ? because it is having trouble processing

I added a comment in my answer below

You need to follow the rules for Json and escape <, > and "
&lt;Parameter Name=&quot;BatchId&quot;&gt;0xc70fe820ee010080&lt;/Parameter&gt;

The sequence is:

Deserialize your json
Create an XML document from your string property
Do whatever you want with the Xml

Something like (not tested):
var foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<requestDTO>(jsonString);
var xmlString = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(foo.messageContent);
var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
var parameterNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Parameter");
var batchId = parameterNode.InnerText;
var parameterName = parameterNode.Attributes["Name"].Value;

